# Create a new row with widths that differ from first row of table in Power BI SSRS paginated report builder

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, powerbi-paginated-reports

Is there a way to give a singular field (that is below a row with multiple columns) its own row in a paginated report table?

I am trying to create a report that displays various information for help tickets including fields like the submission date, subject, ticket status, etc. I am trying to get all the info on one table so it is displayed like:

ticket table:

| Column A | Column B | Column C | Column D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| field a | field b | field c | field d |
| field e | continuation of e | continuation of e | continuation of e |
| field | field | field | field |
| field e | continuation of e | continuation of e | continuation of e |

Unfortunately I cannot figure out a way to give the ticket comment its own row. It just gets grouped in that first column. Basically I just want the recent comment field to stretch across the length of the table

[image: table in report builder, want Most_Recent_Comment to have its own full row instead of being stuck in submission date column]

[image: when testing out table comment field just gets stuck in that first column]

Any ideas on how I can give the ticket comment its own full row?

Thanks!

I tried inserting the comment field in that first column expecting it to automatically go the width of the table but it get stuck in the width of the first column. I also tried creating a matrix, but the result appeared the same as the table visual.  Also tried creating another table but then all the comments get displayed after the rest of the ticket info.
I want it to be like: ticket info 1 , comment 1, ticket info 2, comment 2
as opposed to: ticket info 1, ticket info 2, comment 1, comment 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is quite simple.

Create a table in your report and add all the fields except your comment field.

Test the report and you should get 1 rows per row in the dataset. Now the basics are OK, right click on any cell from the data row (not the header) and choose "insert row / inside group - below."

Now you can merge all the textboxes on that row and then select your comments field in it. That should be it!

Here's a 30 second gif to show you it in action. (Right-click the animation and choose "open link in new window" if it's too small)

[image]